# How do I get DD-WRT to emit a non-broken openvpn configuration for shared-secret (static key)?

Tags: openvpn, dd-wrt

I recently had to replace my house router and I installed DD-WRT on the replacement.  Unfortunately it seems to generate a defective client openvpn.conf.  Openvpn gives the following error:

```
Options error: specify only one of --tls-server, --tls-client, or --secret
```

The configuration that DD-wrt builds from the settings in the gui is

```
secret /tmp/openvpncl/static.key
verb 3
mute 3
syslog
writepid /var/run/openvpncl.pid
client
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
script-security 2
dev tun1
proto udp4
cipher aes-256-cbc
auth sha256
remote $host $port
tun-mtu 1500
fragment 1300
mssfix
fast-io
keepalive 30 300
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
ifconfig $lip $rip
log /tmp/openvpn.log
```

If I remove the `client` directive then openvpn works just fine.  Is there a way to get DD-WRT to generate a valid openvpn.conf for use with shared secret OpenVPN tunnels?  Has no one used the `Static Key` box in the web GUI in the past few years?